# My application works on android emulator but not on my device

Tags: android, android-emulator, facebook-login

My application is running on the emulator no problem, but it does not work on my handset,
*Samsung Galaxy Nexus S*.

The application consist of different logins, including, Facebook, Twitter, Mendeley and my own web application.

I do not know why it is not working. On Facebook, in application settings I have also added the hash code required but it really does not work. Maybe it is something related to `http` request(s) to the servers from the device. Stressed about it, please help

Here are the logs

```
07-18 23:23:32.826: D/AndroidRuntime(430): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-18 23:23:32.826: D/AndroidRuntime(430): CheckJNI is ON
07-18 23:23:33.725: D/AndroidRuntime(430): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
07-18 23:23:33.965: D/dalvikvm(249): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 54% free 2545K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 77ms
07-18 23:23:33.965: W/ActivityManager(67): No content provider found for: 
07-18 23:23:34.371: W/ActivityManager(67): No content provider found for: 
07-18 23:23:34.405: D/PackageParser(67): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-873505620.tmp
07-18 23:23:34.745: I/PackageManager(67): Removing non-system package:com.facebook.android
07-18 23:23:34.745: I/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.facebook.android uid=10034
07-18 23:23:34.865: I/Process(67): Sending signal. PID: 401 SIG: 9
07-18 23:23:34.865: I/ActivityManager(67):   Force finishing activity HistoryRecord{4059c7a0 com.facebook.android/.PushpinMobileActivity}
07-18 23:23:35.072: I/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{40718cf0 com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.PushpinMobileActivity paused=true}
07-18 23:23:35.085: E/InputDispatcher(67): channel '407dd068 com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.Dashboard (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-18 23:23:35.085: E/InputDispatcher(67): channel '407dd068 com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.Dashboard (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-18 23:23:35.145: I/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{407dd068 com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.Dashboard paused=false}
07-18 23:23:35.456: D/PackageManager(67): Scanning package com.facebook.android
07-18 23:23:35.485: I/PackageManager(67): Package com.facebook.android codePath changed from /data/app/com.facebook.android-1.apk to /data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
07-18 23:23:35.526: I/PackageManager(67): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk
07-18 23:23:35.715: W/InputManagerService(67): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 401 uid 10034
07-18 23:23:36.130: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk' ---
07-18 23:23:38.285: D/dalvikvm(439): DexOpt: load 135ms, verify+opt 948ms
07-18 23:23:38.646: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk' (success) ---
07-18 23:23:38.646: W/PackageManager(67): Code path for pkg : com.facebook.android changing from /data/app/com.facebook.android-1.apk to /data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk
07-18 23:23:38.646: W/PackageManager(67): Resource path for pkg : com.facebook.android changing from /data/app/com.facebook.android-1.apk to /data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk
07-18 23:23:38.655: D/PackageManager(67):   Activities: com.facebook.android.PushpinMobileActivity com.facebook.android.OAuthAccessTokenActivity com.facebook.android.Dashboard com.facebook.android.MendeleyAcessTokenActivity
07-18 23:23:38.845: D/dalvikvm(67): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1240K, 48% free 4374K/8391K, external 3520K/3903K, paused 185ms
07-18 23:23:38.855: I/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.facebook.android uid=10034
07-18 23:23:39.180: I/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.facebook.android-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.facebook.android-2.apk@classes.dex
07-18 23:23:39.180: D/PackageManager(67): New package installed in /data/app/com.facebook.android-2.apk
07-18 23:23:39.576: I/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.facebook.android uid=10034
07-18 23:23:39.795: D/dalvikvm(159): GC_EXPLICIT freed 194K, 50% free 2942K/5831K, external 2985K/3727K, paused 205ms
07-18 23:23:39.915: D/dalvikvm(131): GC_EXPLICIT freed 68K, 50% free 2964K/5895K, external 4803K/5279K, paused 183ms
07-18 23:23:40.285: D/dalvikvm(183): GC_EXPLICIT freed 128K, 52% free 2758K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 422ms
07-18 23:23:40.445: I/dalvikvm(159): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
07-18 23:23:40.545: W/RecognitionManagerService(67): no available voice recognition services found
07-18 23:23:41.105: D/dalvikvm(67): GC_EXPLICIT freed 424K, 49% free 4285K/8391K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 108ms
07-18 23:23:41.245: I/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.facebook.android-1.apk@classes.dex
07-18 23:23:41.295: D/AndroidRuntime(430): Shutting down VM
07-18 23:23:41.327: I/AndroidRuntime(430): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-18 23:23:41.335: D/dalvikvm(430): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 72% free 295K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+1ms
07-18 23:23:41.335: D/jdwp(430): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-18 23:23:41.335: D/dalvikvm(430): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-18 23:23:41.545: I/Launcher(131): setLoadOnResume
07-18 23:23:42.055: D/AndroidRuntime(444): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-18 23:23:42.055: D/AndroidRuntime(444): CheckJNI is ON
07-18 23:23:42.985: D/AndroidRuntime(444): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-18 23:23:43.066: I/ActivityManager(67): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.facebook.android/.PushpinMobileActivity } from pid 444
07-18 23:23:43.135: I/ActivityManager(67): Start proc com.facebook.android for activity com.facebook.android/.PushpinMobileActivity: pid=452 uid=10034 gids={3003}
07-18 23:23:43.155: D/AndroidRuntime(444): Shutting down VM
07-18 23:23:43.175: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 320K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+1ms
07-18 23:23:43.205: I/AndroidRuntime(444): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-18 23:23:43.205: D/jdwp(444): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-18 23:23:43.205: D/dalvikvm(444): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-18 23:23:43.585: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 456ms
07-18 23:23:43.755: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 168ms
07-18 23:23:44.097: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 324ms
07-18 23:23:44.567: I/ActivityManager(67): Displayed com.facebook.android/.PushpinMobileActivity: +1s447ms
07-18 23:23:45.145: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(159): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-18 23:23:49.746: D/dalvikvm(237): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 55% free 2597K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 85ms
07-18 23:23:54.886: D/dalvikvm(159): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 50% free 2944K/5831K, external 3005K/3727K, paused 145ms
07-18 23:23:59.906: D/dalvikvm(249): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2544K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 111ms
07-18 23:24:05.186: D/dalvikvm(311): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 50ms
07-18 23:24:20.515: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 819K, 56% free 2723K/6151K, external 1793K/2137K, paused 74ms
07-18 23:24:25.196: W/InputManagerService(67): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40658160
07-18 23:24:30.906: I/Database(452): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
07-18 23:24:35.826: W/InputManagerService(67): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406c8c70
07-18 23:24:53.035: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1052K, 55% free 3042K/6727K, external 2079K/2562K, paused 20ms+11ms
07-18 23:25:03.306: I/fbID(452): 518993454
07-18 23:25:03.316: I/fb_token(452): <....>
07-18 23:25:03.436: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_CONCURRENT freed 803K, 55% free 3093K/6727K, external 2079K/2562K, paused 16ms+6ms
07-18 23:25:04.426: I/dalvikvm(452): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
07-18 23:25:08.706: I/System.out(452): Access Token = 
07-18 23:25:08.716: I/System.out(452): Backend Response to Token Request:
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Access Token = <....>
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): UserID = 70
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Username = <....>
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Expiration Timestamp = 1342697101
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Facebook Token = <....>
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Twitter Token = <....>
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Twitter Token Secret = <....>
07-18 23:25:08.727: I/System.out(452): Mendeley Token = 
07-18 23:25:08.739: I/System.out(452): Mendeley Token Secret = 
07-18 23:25:08.817: I/ActivityManager(67): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.facebook.android/.Dashboard (has extras) } from pid 452
07-18 23:25:09.586: I/System.out(452): Got it! Lets see what we found...
07-18 23:25:09.586: I/System.out(452): 200
07-18 23:25:09.656: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 405K, 55% free 3043K/6727K, external 2129K/2562K, paused 70ms
07-18 23:25:12.706: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 58K, 53% free 3220K/6727K, external 2150K/2562K, paused 78ms
07-18 23:25:12.706: I/dalvikvm-heap(452): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.872MB for 87396-byte allocation
07-18 23:25:12.846: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 52% free 3306K/6855K, external 2150K/2562K, paused 66ms
07-18 23:25:13.026: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 52% free 3306K/6855K, external 2150K/2562K, paused 106ms
07-18 23:25:13.026: I/dalvikvm-heap(452): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.956MB for 87396-byte allocation
07-18 23:25:13.216: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 52% free 3391K/6983K, external 2150K/2562K, paused 123ms
07-18 23:25:13.596: W/ImageDownloader(452): Incorrect URL: 
07-18 23:25:13.746: D/dalvikvm(452): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 234K, 53% free 3319K/6983K, external 2272K/2562K, paused 57ms
07-18 23:25:14.956: I/ActivityManager(67): Displayed com.facebook.android/.Dashboard: +5s947ms
```

Comment: what do you mean not working? errors? can you post the LogCat?

Comment: How does it "does not work"? More specifics?

Comment: I was running my application on the emulator it works, but when i run it on android device it gives me error like Login Failed: invalid_key: Android key mismatch. Your key * does not match the allowed keys in your application settings... and for twitter and mendeley and my own rest server it just stops to work :(

Comment: can you tell me how to add the log in the question

Comment: finally i have added the logs as well.. Please help

Comment: Seriously, you should never ever post your unfiltered log cat to public spaces. It contained a whole bunch of access and secret tokens for Facebook and Twitter as well as user names. I removed the sensitive information for you.

Comment: thanks, but can someone please help me out ?

Comment: I have solved the issue .. how should i post the answer ? anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming because I was using webview for Mendeley and Twitter on Android using scribe library. And I have solved it here

[android webview function onPagefinished is called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601134/android-webview-function-onpagefinished-is-called-twice)

And for Facebook the problem was because I was not adding the correct hash key the method given on Facebook page for Windows does not give you correct hash key. Please install openSSL to generate the key.